# Postfix cannot resolve local IPs from Name Server

Tags: dns, postfix, ip

I currently have a server running "Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS" installed with

- Postfix
- Bind 9 (Slave)

The postfix cannot seem to resolve my internal IPs to Name Server (PTR) entry I have within bind9 settings.

eg. I am wanting DNS to resolve `192.168.0.20` to `priv-000-020.internal.domain.com` by using a `bind9 "168.192.in-addr.arpa` record in my maste/slave folder which contains a record like this:-

```
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
$GENERATE 1-254 $       PTR    priv-000-$.internal.domain.com
```

I have checked using `nslookup` & `dig`, both work fine without any issues resolving IP to the name.

I have made sure that the name server is the first in the list:-

```
/etc/resolv.conf 
/var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf
```

I have also tried also going into `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and added

```
smtp_host_lookup = native,dns
```

I am only using this system to relay emails to my exchange server & that works perfectly but try to get this name resolving issue fixed.

Not sure if this is important to anyone but if I remove "native" I cannot relay emails to my exchange server.

I know I can use hosts & that appears to work fine but was really wanting to keep the same setup & not have to manually enter every single IP address into the hosts file.

Hopefully someone with better linux knowledge can help me as I have wasted nearly 6 hours on trying to resolve this issue with any success.